# button onclick bind event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML, I have a button list. If user clicks a button,
`doCommand` function will be called. 
The code is following,

```
<ul>
<li class="button1" onclick="doCommand('bold');" id="bold-button" title="bold">B</li>
<li class="button2" onclick="doCommand('bold');" id="italic-button" title="bold">I</li>
<li class="button3" onclick="doCommand('bold');" id="underline-button" title="bold">U</li>
<li class="button4" onclick="doCommand('bold');" id="strikethrough-button" title="bold">S</li>
</ul>
```

This is plain expression, normal web programmer will code like that. 
But, I want to hide `onclick` event and its function for security reason.
So the HTML code will be like this,

```
<ul>
<li class="button1" id="bold-button" title="bold">B</li>
<li class="button2" id="italic-button" title="bold">I</li>
<li class="button3" id="underline-button" title="bold">U</li>
<li class="button4" id="strikethrough-button" title="bold">S</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?
Hiding `onclick` property but do the same work.
I am using jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript click event listener on class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you set the same class for the btns, you could easily do:

markup:

```
<ul>
<li class="button1 clickable" id="bold-button" title="bold">B</li>
<li class="button2 clickable" id="italic-button" title="bold">I</li>
<li class="button3 clickable" id="underline-button" title="bold">U</li>
<li class="button4 clickable" id="strikethrough-button" title="bold">S</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){/* doCommand('bold') or whatever */})
```

**Edit**: if you want on click to directly transform the text to bold, you could use the *this* (that refers to the element you clicked, and you need to wrap it inside jQuery $) keyword inside the function i.e.

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){$(this).css('font-weight','bold')})
```

Comment: but, how can I know which button was clicked?

Comment: inside the function, the "this" refers to the li 'button' you clicked.. if you alert this.id it will show you the right id for each button..

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my example with an example of *this* ;)

Answer (score 5):

The class should be the same at all buttons, like this:

```
<li class="button button1"...
<li class="button button2"...
```

Then, you can do like this in javascript.

```
$("li.button").click(function() {
  doCommand('bold');
});
```

Comment: Maybe we can reuse the title attribute? doCommand(this.attr('title'));

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your markup and using vanilla JS you can do it the following way.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul');

list.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('button1')) {
    console.log('bold');
  };
  if (e.target.classList.contains('button2')) {
    console.log('italics');
  };
  if (e.target.classList.contains('button3')) {
    console.log('underline');
  };
  if (e.target.classList.contains('button4')) {
    console.log('strikethrough');
  };

})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="button1" id="bold-button" title="bold">B</li>
  <li class="button2" id="italic-button" title="bold">I</li>
  <li class="button3" id="underline-button" title="bold">U</li>
  <li class="button4" id="strikethrough-button" title="bold">S</li>
</ul>
```

I assign the event to the parent list, and check the class of the target allowing to do whatever action needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's document ready event to wire up the events:

---

```
$(function()
{
    $("#bold-button").click(function(){doCommand('bold');});
}
);
```