# JavaScript click event listener on class

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm currently trying to write some JavaScript to get the attribute of the class that has been clicked. I know that to do this the correct way, I should use an event listener. 
My code is as follows:

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
    alert(attribute);
};

classname.addEventListener('click', myFunction(), false);
```

I was expecting to get an alert box every time I clicked on one of the classes to tell me the attribute but unfortunately this does not work. Can anyone help please?

(**Note** - *I can quite easily do this in `jQuery` but I would **NOT** like to use it*)

Comment: There's a problem with the code that's adding the event listener. addEventListener takes the event name ('click'), reference to the function (not the result of the function as it is now by calling myFunction() with parens) and a flag to indicate event bubbling. The addEventListener call should look like: elem.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false) and classname is a NodeList type. Need to loop over all the elements and attach the listener to each one in the list.

Answer (score 596, accepted):

This should work. `getElementsByClassName` returns an  Array-like object (see below) of the elements matching the criteria.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
    alert(attribute);
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

jQuery does the looping part for you, which you need to do in plain JavaScript.

If you have **ES6 support** you can replace your last line with:

```
    Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
    });
```

Note: Older browsers (like IE6, IE7, IE8) don´t support `getElementsByClassName` and so they return `undefined`.

---

**Details on `getElementsByClassName`**

`getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, but a `HTMLCollection` in most, or a `NodeList` in some browsers ([Mozilla ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)). Both of these types are Array-Like, (meaning that they have a length property and the objects can be accessed via their index), but are not strictly an Array or inherited from an Array (meaning other methods that can be performed on an Array cannot be performed on these types).

Thanks to user @[Nemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333493/nemo) for pointing this out and having me dig in to fully understand.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I actually didn't realise that jQuery did the looping. Great help Anudeep. Here's your working answer: http://jsfiddle.net/LWda3/2/

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` actually always return an array, even if only one element matches the criteria

Comment: Careful though the first element of the array is all the dom elements. So start your for loop with 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13258908/1333493 "document.getElementsByClassName does not return an array. It returns a node list which is traversed like an XML file."

Comment: `Array.from()` has a second parameter which is a map function so the above (assuming es6 support) could be written `Array.from(classname, c => c.addEventListener('click', myFunction));`.

Comment: What happens if the number of tags with the class changes? For example, one is deleted? Would manual cleanup of the event listener be required?

Comment: Please note that Array.from does not support on IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: What if elements from that class are constantly being added and removed?

Comment: @RobertMoore see my answer, should help with that

Comment: Better attach event to a parent and delegates it in place to attach it to every single element.

Answer (score 64):

With modern JavaScript it can be done like this:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.a');

divs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute("data-el"));
}));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    .a {
      background-color:red;
      height: 33px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .b {
      background-color:#00AA00;
      height: 50px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="a" data-el="1">1</div>
  <div class="b" data-el="no-click-handler">2</div>
  <div class="a" data-el="3">11</div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Gets all elements by class name
2. Loops over all elements with using forEach
3. Attach an event listener on each element
4. Uses `event.target` to retrieve more information for specific element

Comment: This is what I used, but I can't vote this answer as useful since you deviated away from what the function in the question is trying to do. You should really update your answer to pull the data attribute value rather than a class name.

Comment: @Mark Thank you :) I have updated as you required. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 26):

You can use the code below:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.className === 'databox') {
        alert(this)
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: I'll have to give this a try, it's a unique approach which might actually be easier to maintain and perform better than looping!

Comment: if the element has multiple classes, you would have to check for the correct value in that fields eg. classes and order. i'd rather go for `evt.target.classList.contains('databox')`

Comment: This seems wildly inefficient to me. Every single event on the body would go through this function. What's so hard to maintain about a loop?

Comment: This is very inefficient, you would go through each element as @JosefAssad said.

Comment: Not recommending this approach as just adding too much overhead to front-end

Comment: I fully disagree with everybody here. If you use  element.addEventListener('click', event => { } to add the event to the element, the javascript will check every click internally anyway. If you add the event to all element of classes Javascript will run equivalent check instances for every single click, while the above approach will only look once for every single click.

Comment: @honk31 dear friend. Actually the above method is more efficient than any answer here

Comment: I really like this approach when inefficiency is not a concern.

Comment: This should work really well, especially when elements of a class are created on the fly.

Comment: @Thanasis I'm with you on this one. Event delegation is not inherently less efficient than direct assignment of listeners. The same event capturing and bubbling processes take place in either scenario. In fact, it can be argued that event delegation actually *increases* efficiency, since it avoids the violation of the DRY principle that assigning the same event handler to a collection of like elements necessarily entails.

Comment: @GabrielSalinasSzada I really like this approach when inefficiency *is* a concern, personally.

Answer (score 24):

*** This was edited to allow for children of the target class to trigger the events. See bottom of the answer for details. ***

An alternative answer to add an event listener to a class where items are frequently being added and removed. This is inspired by jQuery's `on` function where you can pass in a selector for a child element that the event is listening on.

```
var base = document.querySelector('#base'); // the container for the variable content
var selector = '.card'; // any css selector for children

base.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // find the closest parent of the event target that
  // matches the selector
  var closest = event.target.closest(selector);
  if (closest && base.contains(closest)) {
    // handle class event
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u6oje7af/94/

This will listen for clicks on children of the `base` element and if the target of a click has a parent matching the selector, the class event will be handled. You can add and remove elements as you like without having to add more click listeners to the individual elements. This will catch them all even for elements added after this listener was added, just like the jQuery functionality (which I imagine is somewhat similar under the hood).

This depends on the events propagating, so if you `stopPropagation` on the event somewhere else, this may not work. Also, the `closest` function has some compatibility issues with IE apparently (what doesn't?).

This could be made into a function if you need to do this type of action listening repeatedly, like

```
function addChildEventListener(base, eventName, selector, handler) {
  base.addEventListener(eventName, function(event) {
    var closest = event.target.closest(selector);
    if (closest && base.contains(closest)) {
      // passes the event to the handler and sets `this`
      // in the handler as the closest parent matching the
      // selector from the target element of the event
      handler.call(closest, event);
    }
  });
}
```

=========================================
EDIT: This post originally used the `matches` function for DOM elements on the event target, but this restricted the targets of events to the direct class only. It has been updated to use the `closest` function instead, allowing for events on children of the desired class to trigger the events as well. The original `matches` code can be found at the original fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u6oje7af/23/

Answer (score 4):

Yow can use querySelectorAll to select all the classes and loop through them to assign the eventListener. The if condition checks if it contains the class name.

```
const arrClass = document.querySelectorAll(".className");
for (let i of arrClass) {
  i.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("className")) {
        console.log("Perfrom Action")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Unless you suspect the className to dynamically change, you shouldn't have to recheck the className of the even target.

Answer (score 3):

All the above-mentioned answers are correct and I just want to demonstrate another short way

```
document.querySelectorAll('.classname').forEach( button => {
    button.onclick = function () {
    // rest of code
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution  Short and focused on the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider that if you click a button, the **target** of the event listener is not necessaily the button itself, but whatever content inside the button you clicked on. You can reference the element to which you assigned the listener using the **currentTarget** property. Here is a pretty solution in modern ES using a single statement:

```
    document.querySelectorAll(".myClassName").forEach(i => i.addEventListener(
        "click",
        e => {
            alert(e.currentTarget.dataset.myDataContent);
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach for many DOM elements with the same class name by selecting path key in the eventListener object.

Add an event listener to the immediate parent class wrapping all the child elements with the same class and get the path by selecting the first key in the event object.

E.g say you want to edit table cells of a table

```
    //Select tbody element & add  event listener
    let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

    tbody.addEventListener("click", function(e,v) {
    // Get the clicked cell
    let cell = e.path[0];
    // Get the current cell value
    let cellValue = cell.innerHTML;
    //Rest of code goes here
    }
```