# Use button clicked in Switch statement

Tags: javascript

I have 3 buttons on my web page called `btn_newsletter_wide`, `btn_newsletter_desktop` and `btn_newsletter_mobile` that should submit a form, but before doing so I want to apply some specific validation depending on the button pressed. All the buttons have an onclick action to one function that determines the validation to apply via a Switch select as below;

```
function validate_forms() {

    var btnSelected = (this.id)

    switch (btnSelected) {

        case "btn_newsletter_wide":
             validate_form_newsletter_wide( form );
             break;

        case "btn_newsletter_desktop":
             validate_form_newsletter_wide( form );
             break;

        case "btn_newsletter_mobile":
             validate_form_newsletter_wide( form );
             break;
    }


}
```

But does not seem to work, on debugging it I find that `btnSelected=undefined` so the calls to the right function don't happen. So it must be something with the way that I am trying to pass the ID of the button selected to the variable, after some tinkering I can't correct it.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: where do you call `validate_forms`, include the code?

Comment: pass this in validate_forms(). Example: validate_forms(this)

Comment: You should be getting "event" object inside the click handler which will have "target" property which will refer to the actual node being clicked. That should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your inlining the event on button you must explcitly pass this object reference

```
<button id="yourbutton" onclick="validate_form(this)"> // pass this object explicitly

// or addEventListener more recommended way to do 
document.getElementById("yourbutton").addEventListener("click", validate_form);

// or attach onclick event
document.getElementById("yourbutton").onclick = validate_form;
```

To attach same function  for multiple elements see this link [JavaScript click event listener on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)