# External dependency clashing with preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Take a look at the following JavaScript for me that opens a pop up window, please:

```
function openPopup(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
}
var el = document.querySelector(".bbc-popup");
el.addEventListener("click", openPopup);
```

Here is a JSFiddle of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/dvadcgps/1/

However, when I include it on my page, the code doesn't work, and the link opens in the current tab. The *only* external JavaScript resources I rely on are jQuery (1.11.3) and Bootstrap 3, and those are both included within the above fiddle, to no effect.

What other reasons could there be for this code to not work?

Here is the full `HTML` code of the page, with all external resources included, for you to see how it stops working... the links that should open popups are behind the **View Chairs' Builds** button:

http://jsfiddle.net/e60y004n/1/

Comment: Your code works fine for me in that I see a new 600x600 popup window (Chrome 46 on W8.1). I would imagine the preferences for whether a new window is allowed to be opened or is opened in a new tab is down to the user settings in the browser.

Comment: You're only adding the event listener to the first `.chair-popup` element. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class).

Comment: Fantastic, Brian. This seems to work now: http://jsfiddle.net/e60y004n/3/ Pop it in an answer and I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off [Brian Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429925/brian-ray)'s comment, I had to ensure the Event Listener was added to every element, as my current code was only adding it to the first.

Firstly, I add all the elements I want to be targeted to an array.

```
var chairPopup = document.getElementsByClassName("chair-popup");
```

I then loop through every element in that array, adding the Event Listener to each:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chairPopup.length; i++) {
    chairPopup[i].addEventListener("click", openPopup);
}
```

The full code, with the `function()`, reads as follows:

```
var chairPopup = document.getElementsByClassName("chair-popup");

function openPopup(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href, "popupWindow", "width=300,height=1000,scrollbars=yes");
}
for (var i = 0; i < chairPopup.length; i++) {
    chairPopup[i].addEventListener("click", openPopup);
}
```

In an answer that has since been deleted by it's author, they mentioned a need to change `popupWindow` to `_blank` within the `window.open()` function. I can confirm that this is needed, otherwise each link opens up in the *same* popup window.

```
window.open(this.href, "_blank", "width=300,height=1000,scrollbars=yes");
```