# How do I make this work with multiple id's

Tags: javascript

I think there's an easy answer, but I can't find the right solution for this. I know that it has to be done with `querySelectorAll`, but can't figure out how to use it in this case.

I have elements with ID's `#modalA`, `#modalB` and `#modalC`. I don't want to  duplicate code. So I want to figure out what is the best practice for this?

Can't use getElementByClassName, because I can't make changes to markup.

```js
var getModalsA = document.getElementById('modalA');
var getModalsB = document.getElementById('modalB');
var getModalsC = document.getElementById('modalC');

getModalsA.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript click event listener on class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)

Comment: Don't use IDs, use classes.

Comment: Can't use getElementByClassName, because I can't make changes to markup. Need solution with existing markup. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're simply after a small refactoring.

Something like:

```
function addListenersToElement(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

  }, false);
}

var ids = ['modalA', 'modalB', 'modalC'];
ids.forEach(addListenersToElement);
```

I would use jQuery or similar for stuff like this (or a lightweight variant), but if you can't change the page markup, probably your best bet is to refactor the code in smaller functions.