# Why the event doesn't execute?

Tags: javascript, events, simple-html-dom

Hey guys could anyone explain why the event doesn't execute?
The debugger doesn't give any error at all!
Thank you in advance

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <button class="boton">prueba</button>
  <body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var elemento= document.getElementsByClassName("boton")
elemento.onclick=function(){
  alert("hola");
};
debugger;

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `var elemento= document.getElementsByClassName("boton")[0]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript click event listener on class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)

Comment: Worked , Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The DOM method `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array. You must loop through the array items before assigning the `onclick` handler:

```js
var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName("boton")
for (var i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++) {
  elemento[i].onclick = function() {
    alert("hola");
  };
}
debugger;
```

```html
<button class="boton">prueba</button>
```

Alternatively, if you are selecting only one element, you can use `document.querySelector()`:

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector(".boton");
elemento.onclick = function() {
  alert("hola");
};
debugger;
```

```html
<button class="boton">prueba</button>
```