# How to fire the javascript function in the textboxes that are getting created dynamically in asp .net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Below is my code which creates the textboxes dynamically in modal pop up each time when i click add button and removes the text boxes in that row each time when i click remove button which is working fine till here the problem is i have the javascript function which validates the month date and year in text box that if if we give any number greater than 12 it shows message that month should be less than 12 similarly for date also it will accept till 31 but if it is greater than 31 it shows error message and similarly year also but this is done for our asp text boxes how can i make this javascript function to work in modal pop where the textboxes are created dynamically

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
             if (value == "") {
                 FillDropdown()
                 return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox"  value = "' + value + '" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name = "DynamicTextBox" >"' + Hours + '"</Select><b>:</b><select name = "DynamicTextBox">"' + Min + '"</Select>' +
                          ' <input id="btnAdd123" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" /><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
                 //Min = "";
                 // Hours = "";
                 // 
             }

         }
         var HHEdit = "";
         var MMEdit = "";
         function GetDynamicTextBox1(value) {


             values = value.split(' ');
             one = values[0];
             two = values[1];

             values = two.split(':');
             three = values[0];
             Four = values[1];




             HHEdit = three;
             MMEdit = Four;
             FillDropdown()

             return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox"  value = "' + one + '" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name = "DynamicTextBox" >"' + Hours + '"</Select><b>:</b><select name = "DynamicTextBox">"' + Min + '"</Select>' +
                        ' <input id="btnAdd123" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" /><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
            //   $('.DynamicTextBox').val(one);
         }
         function AddTextBox() {
             var div = document.createElement('DIV');
             div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
             document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
         }
         function AddTextBox1() {
             var inputCount = document.getElementById('TextBoxContainer').getElementsByTagName('input').length;
             if (inputCount == "0") {
                 var div = document.createElement('DIV');
                 div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
                 document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
             }


         }
         function RemoveTextBox(div) {
             document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
         }

         function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
             var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
         if (values != null) {
             var html = "";
             for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                 html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox1(values[i]) + "</div>";
             }
             document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
         }
     }

     var Hours = "";
     var Min = "";
     function FillDropdown() {
         for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
             if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
                 if (HHEdit != "" && HHEdit == i) {
                     Hours += '<option value="' + i + '" selected="selected">' + " 0" + i + " " + '</option>'
                 }
                 else {
                     Hours += '<option value="' + i + '">' + " 0" + i + " " + '</option>';
                 }
             }
             else {
                 if (HHEdit != "" && HHEdit == i) {
                     Hours += '<option value="' + i + '" selected="selected">' + " " + i + " " + '</option>';
                 }
                 else {
                     Hours += '<option value="' + i + '">' + " " + i + " " + '</option>';
                 }
             }


         }
         for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
             if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
                 if (MMEdit != "" && MMEdit == i) {
                     Min += '<option value="' + i + '"  selected="selected">' + " 0" + i + " " + '</option>';
                 }
                 else {
                     Min += '<option value="' + i + '">' + " 0" + i + " " + '</option>';
                 }
             }
             else {
                 if (MMEdit != "" && MMEdit == i) {
                     Min += '<option value="' + i + '" selected="selected">' + " " + i + " " + '</option>';
                 }
                 else {

                     Min += '<option value="' + i + '">' + " " + i + " " + '</option>';
                 }
             }

         }
         //$('#Item').append(option);
     }


     window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;
</script>
```

***Code for date month year validation using javascript***

```
var fdate = document.getElementById('<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>').value;
                 var tdate = document.getElementById('<%=txtToDate.ClientID%>').value;
                 var fromdate = fdate.split('/');
                 var fmonth = fromdate[0];
                 var fdate = fromdate[1];
                 var fyear = fromdate[2];
                 if (fmonth > 12) {
                     message += "From Month Should Be Less Than 12." + "\n";
                 }
                 if (fdate > 31) {
                     message += "From Date Cannot Be Greater Than 31." + "\n";
                 }
                 if (fyear < 2000 || fyear > 2030) {
                     message += "From Year Should Be In Between 2000 to 2030." + "\n";
                 }
                 var todate = tdate.split('/');
                 var tmonth = todate[0];
                 var tdate = todate[1];
                 var tyear = todate[2];
                 if (tmonth > 12) {
                     message += "To Month Should Be Less Than 12." + "\n";
                 }
                 if (tdate > 31) {
                     message += "To Date Cannot Be Greater Than 31." + "\n";
                 }
                 if (tyear < 2000 || tyear > 2030) {
                     message += "To Year Should Be In Between 2000 to 2030."+"\n";
                 }
                 if (message != "") {
                     alert(message);
                     return false;
                 }
From Date: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" Width="113px" runat="server" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" onkeypress="return IsValidData(event);" ondrop="return false;"
        onpaste="return false;" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'')"></asp:TextBox>  <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Invalid Character</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    To Date: <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" Width="113px" runat="server" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" onkeypress="return IsValidData(event);" ondrop="return false;"
        onpaste="return false;" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'')"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span1" style="color: Red; display: none">* Invalid Character</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: did you tried with `onchange` ?

Comment: yes it is working with asp text boxes but it is not working for dynamically created textboxes

Comment: I don't see the part where you're adding a client-side event handler to your dynamically created client-side controls. No client-side events will occur unless you explicitly add an event handler to the control after creating it.

Comment: i am very new to this so could you please help me out how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you've actually defined your IsValidData function. I'm assuming that you've done that somewhere...

You can pass **this** to your IsValidData function as a parameter to work with the element that triggered the event in your function..

Also you should try moving away from inline functions to event listeners. This stack post ([JavaScript click event listener on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)) talks about applying an event listener to a class of DOM elements.

If you are using jQuery, since you included this tag, then I'd encourage you to look into the jQuery .on() function to add event handlers. It'll make everything much easier (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

If you do not know what a javascript event listener is, then start here (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Comment: i am not at all having isvalid data function in my code could you please show me by editing my code as i am new to this concept

Comment: You need to read these two articles: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: i had seen those two articles the code which is in those two articles is similar to ny javascript function my question  is how to fire my javascript function inthis return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox"  value = "' + value + '" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name = "DynamicTextBox" >"' + Hours + '"</Select><b>:</b><select name = "DynamicTextBox">"' + Min + '"</Select>' +
                          ' <input id="btnAdd123" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" /><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />' dynamically created textboxes

Comment: could any one please show me how to fire my javascript function in <input name = "DynamicTextBox" value = "' + value + '" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"></input>