# Javascript Event listener on class with function parameters,

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

First off, I have read similar issues, the most important being this one:
[JavaScript click event listener on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class).

However, my initial code looks more like the solution of that issue, with the difference that my function needs a parameter.

Basically I had a program with buttons that showed content when clicked and could be nested using Javascript, this was done by having several buttons, each with its respective div and an `onclick` attribute that toggled a class on said div (probably not the best way to do it), this worked just fine until I used `addEventlistener` instead of the `onclick` attribute, as shown below:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('nested-button');
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('nested-div')
function myFunction(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
for (var i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
   buttons[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction(divs[i].id),false);
}
```

First (using the code seen above), the console said it couldn't read the property id of undefined, however, I solved this by making a var with that same value inside the for loop and then use that var as a parameter, the result was, not very surprisingly, that all the buttons toggled show on the last div, so to fix this, I thought inputting  just created a function that did  `myFunction` with that var would be enough since the function would always use the id originally used instead  of the value of the var, however, that changed nothing:

```
for (var i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
   var currentDiv = divs[i].id
   buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() 
   {myFunction(currentDiv)},false);
}
```

Finally since I found a reply that said the result returned by `selectByClassName` first index had the whole list, so I tried changing the initial value of `i` in my original code, but the console still told me it couldn't read the id of undefined.

How should I fix this? (please elaborate, also sorry if my grammar is bad)

Comment: `var` has function level scope, not block level scope.

Comment: Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript