# How to check multiple select fields if something is selected

Tags: javascript, validation

I do have a form with a variable amount of dropdowns I want to check, if something is selected before submit.

What I have is this javascript, but it works for the 1st dropdown only.

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("status");
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
     if (selectedValue == "")
    {
     alert("Machine status must be selected");
     return false;
    }
```

for this dropdown (this comes from a loop so I have a variable amount of them within the form)

```
<select name="mstatus[]" id="status">
  <option value="">please select</option>
  <option value="status1">ok</option>
  <option value="status2">not ok</option>
</select>
```

Any hint in the right direction, much appreciated. thanks

Comment: `getElementById()` only returns the first match of the ID. Also, in the HTML standard, it is assumed every ID is unique to one element only. Try using `getElementsByClassName()` and tagging your `select` elements with a class.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving the selects you wish to iterate through the same class and use Jquerys `.each()`. https://api.jquery.com/each/

For the validation I would use a `data` tag to help you with the alert label

```
<select class="form-select" data-label="Machine status"></select>
```

Then the JS code

```
$('.form-select').each(function(index, element) {
    let value = $(element).val();
    let label = $(element).data("label");
     if (value === "") {
        alert(`${label} status must be selected`);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Without Jquery you could do.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.form-select').forEach(function (element, index) {
//do same code here
});
```