# Copy text from ONE of SEVERAL inputs with a SINGLE function (by ID)

Tags: javascript, html

everyone. Working on this HTML document.

I have a function (triggered by a button) that selects and copies the text from an input. Said function works based on the input's ID.

I want to add several inputs and fix the function to get the text of ONE specific input, but so far, I have only been able to make it work by stating the specific ID of ONE input.

Obviously, I don't want to implement a function for every input I will use.

This is my current code:

```
<input type="text" value="AWESOME TEXT" id="1">   

<button id="1" onclick="myFunction()"> Copy</button>
```

And here is the script

```
<script>

function myFunction() {

  var copyText = document.getElementById("1");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}

</script>
```

The function finds the input with the ID "1" and copies the text.
Because I have to sate the "1", it only works with that specific input.

I have tried with:

```
  var copyText = document.getElementById(this.id);
```

and with:

```
  var copyText = document.innerHTML);
```

but to no avail.

So far, my only option is to wirte a function for every input, but not only will this be burdensome and unpractical. It will also bloat my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at this page and use a classname and use an addEventListener https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send the id as a parameter it will work properly. You can do it like this:

```js
function myFunction(myId) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(myId);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="AWESOME TEXT" id="1">   

<button id="1" onclick="myFunction(this.id)"> Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked like a charm.

I hadn't noticed that the button ID must also match the input id.

Thanks a lot.

That was really fast and more than helpful, Pietro Nadalini.