# Get an image source from a button click inside a div?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a div that holds a button and an image. However I want to get that images source from a button click of that specific div. Example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="fn4703gr5e" alt="">
    <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="7876jyhygfd" alt="">
    <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="mnbv5433sda" alt="">
    <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have something similar on a project that I am working on and have had a tough time finding a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810026/how-to-get-image-id-on-click-event

Comment: @ChaseHudson ... Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Comment: @ChaseHudson ... Regarding the so far provided answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, each line is explained in a comment:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".container .inner-container button").forEach(button => {
  //for each button in .inner-container
  button.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked) //execute the function buttonClicked when clicked
})

function buttonClicked() {
  var imageElement = this.parentElement.querySelector("img") //get the image element in the div of the button
  var imageSrc = imageElement.src //get the src of the image
  console.log(imageSrc) //print it
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="fn4703gr5e" alt="">
    <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="7876jyhygfd" alt="">
    <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="mnbv5433sda" alt="">
    <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let img;
let imgSrc;
const btns = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button'));
btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.onclick = () => {
    img = btn.previousElementSibling;
    imgSrc = img.src;
    console.log(img.src);
  };
})
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <img src="fn4703gr5e" alt="">
        <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <img src="7876jyhygfd" alt="">
        <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <img src="mnbv5433sda" alt="">
        <button>Get image source from only the image inside of this div</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Making use of [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) one just needs to implement a single event handler which one registers exactly once at the parent/root node of all elements one wants to handle the inside `'click'` type event from.

The handler could use e.g. [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and the [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) in order to retrieve the button related image's `src` value in an convenient and fail-safe way.

```js
function logButtonClickRelatedImageSource({ target }) {
  const src = target
    .closest('button')
    ?.closest('.inner-container')
    ?.querySelector('img')
    ?.src ?? null;

  if (src !== null) {
    console.log(src);
  }
}

document
  .querySelector('.container')
  .addEventListener('click', logButtonClickRelatedImageSource);
```

```css
button { margin: 10px 0; cursor: pointer; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="fn4703gr5e" alt="">
    <button>log button click related image source</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="7876jyhygfd" alt="">
    <button>log button click related image source</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="mnbv5433sda" alt="">
    <button>log button click related image source</button>
  </div>
</div>
```