# Why the addEventListener property not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

Here is my code

```js
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.current button')

closeBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  closeBtn.parentElement.style.display='none'
})
```

```html
<div class="slide current">
            <div class="content">
                <button class="closeBtn">&times;</button>
                <h1>Orchidaceae</h1>
                <p>
                    There are between 22,000 and 26,000 species in 880 genera. They make up between 6–11% of all seed
                    plants. Orchids can be found in almost every country in the world except for Antarctica.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Could you check what's wrong?

I'm trying to click on the click on the close button on the current slide to hide the content, but it's not showing any error and not any clue!!

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: your github profile works fine - I see no close button on that profile

Comment: your close button click handler just `console.log('click')` - what did you expect to happen?

Comment: oh, I see the problem `const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBtn');` ... that's adding a click listener to a single close button ... and your code has 6 of them

Comment: also, all your flowers are one on top of the other, and I think the click event isn't going to the right element

Comment: I've edited the question now please let me know

Comment: You can use `getElementByClassName` for your `closeBtn` class, then iterate through every element of the class and add your click event listener to all of them.

Comment: This should solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/19655662/4910798

Comment: @Alfred still it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: As @JaromandaX mentioned, your flowers are on top of one another, you can debug it by changing your .slide class position from `absolute` to `relative` temporarily in order to test your click listeners

Comment: Hi, I moved your code to a snippet so that everybody can run it here. From what I see, the code does what is intended to do. What are you trying to achieve here?