# How to change button class on click?

Tags: javascript, html, button, bootstrap-4

I have a button called 'check' that initially uses Bootstrap's 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' class name.  If the condition of the function shown is true I'd like the button's class to change to 'btn btn-success', and if the condition is not met, change the class to 'btn btn-danger'.  I have more than one button on the page that has the same class called 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' so I can't select it by class type, I'm assuming it will have to use the button id.  What I have is not working, I am getting the error, "Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character game_logic.js:34".  Anyone know what this error is referring to?

I would also like the 'check' button to say 'correct' or 'incorrect' after clicking 'check' depending on the condition.

```js
const newProblemBtn = document.querySelector('#start');
const checkBox = document.querySelector('#splash_screen_preference_check_box');

const randomFunc = [
    multiplication,
    division,
    addition,
    subtraction,
]


let mathProblem = document.querySelector('#math_problem').innerText

newProblemBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let result = randomFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomFunc.length)]();
    document.querySelector('#correct_answer').setAttribute('value', result);
});

document.querySelector('#result_check').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (document.querySelector('#correct_answer').getAttribute('value') === document.querySelector('#user_input').value) {
        document.querySelector('#result_check').classList.remove('btn btn-primary btn-lg');
        document.querySelector('#result_check').classList.add('btn btn-success');
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#result_check').classList.remove('btn btn-primary btn-lg');
        document.querySelector('#result_check').classList.add('btn btn-danger');
    }
});

function multiplication() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let problemResult = num1 * num2;
    console.log(num1, '*', num2, '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('math_problem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1} x ${num2}`);
    return problemResult
}


function division() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    let problemResult = (num1 * num2) / num2;
    console.log(num1 * num2, '/', num2, '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('math_problem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1 * num2} ÷ ${num2}`);
    return problemResult
}


function addition() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let problemResult = num1 + num2;
    console.log(num1,'+',num2,'=',problemResult);
    document.getElementById('math_problem').innerHTML =
    (`${num1} + ${num2}`);
    return problemResult
}


function subtraction() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    let numList = [num1, num2];
    numList.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });
    let problemResult = numList[1] - numList[0];
    console.log(numList[1], '-', numList[0], '=', problemResult);
    document.getElementById('math_problem').innerHTML =
    (`${numList[1]} - ${numList[0]}`);
    return problemResult
}
```

```html
<div class="col text-center">
    <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        New Problem
    </button>
    <p id="math_problem"></p>
    <form action="">
        <input id="user_input" type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here">
        <input id="correct_answer" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <br>
    <button id="result_check" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Check</button>
    <script src={% static 'js/game_logic.js' %}></script>
</div>
```

Comment: The error itself looks like it's referring to a syntax error on line 34, specifically an invalid character. Line 34 may or may not actually contain that invalid character, check the line or lines before it to see if there's a syntax error there that might cause the character to be invalid later. As far as your button, if you wanted to reuse the same logic over multiple classes, you could do an eventlistener on the button class and run some logich within the eventlistener. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/19655662/1174822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error with `String contains an invalid character` is because you had spaces inside your `button.classList.remove` calls. You need to split those into separate calls. You also don't need to remove `btn` and then add it again.

For clarity I left out the other js code. The code below will always add the `btn.danger` class but it gets the point across I hope.

```js
document.querySelector('#result_check').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const button = document.querySelector('#result_check');

  if (document.querySelector('#correct_answer').getAttribute('value') === document.querySelector('#user_input').value) {
    button.classList.remove('btn-primary'); // <-- split into two lines
    button.classList.remove('btn-lg'); // <-- split into two lines
    button.classList.add('btn-success');
    button.textContent = 'Correct';
  } else {
    button.classList.remove('btn-lg'); // <-- split into two lines
    button.classList.remove('btn-lg'); // <-- split into two lines
    button.classList.add('btn-danger');
    button.textContent = 'Incorrect';
  }
});
```

```css
/* Just so this is more visible */

.btn-success {
  background: green;
}

.btn-danger {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col text-center">
    <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        New Problem
    </button>
    <p id="math_problem"></p>
    <form action="">
        <input id="user_input" type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here">
        <input id="correct_answer" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <br>
    <button id="result_check" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Check</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I would never have guessed it was complaining about the spaced in the Bootstrap class... I tried your code and it changes the class! Thanks.  Do you know how I could change the word "check" to "Correct" or "Incorrect" depending on if the answer is right or wrong?

Comment: Any chance we could have it reset to the default 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' when "New Problem" is clicked again?  Right it stays green or red after hitting "New Problem" again.

Comment: I mean yes but at this point you should be able to do that yourself no? If you feel this helped you please mark this as the answer

Comment: I can probably figure it out.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need help with is how to change the class of the button, I would try something like this-

```js
var button = document.getElementById('changeClass');
function changeButtonClass() {
  button.class = 'example class 1';
  alert(button.class);
}
// the alert is just for demonstration purposes.
```

```html
<button id='changeClass' class='example class' onclick='changeButtonClass()'>Example button</button>
```

If you want to make it more complex, then just add some if statements and different values to change the class to.

Comment: @Dominik I re-arranged my function and I can get the console to print out the new class that I want but the button doesn't change after I click it.

Comment: What's not changing? the class?

Comment: @Dominik the color of the button isn't changing.  The button class starts out as 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'.  After the onclick function is called, the class changes to 'btn btn-success' but the button doesn't change color or say 'success'.

Comment: BTW I am not the person who answered, I just edited the answer :)

Comment: @Dominik my bad!

Comment: @LlamaButt can you look at the above comments?  I accidentally tagged Dominik instead of you.

Comment: All good, just making sure @LlamaButt is getting the credit

Comment: BTW the code does not work. I just checked. It does not in-fact change the class on the button