# Avoid Triggering Event For 1st Level When Clicking on 2nd Level of Nested HTML Elements (Using JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
     li first generation element
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
           li second generation element
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  ...More li's first generation elements with ul's inside
</ul>
```

And this JQuery event:

```
$(".menu > li").click(function(){
    alert("click");
})
```

The problem that I am running into is that when I click on second generation `li` elements the event is being fired, this is because the first generation `li` element is being clicked too. This is causing that the event is fired in a wrong `li` element. I only want that this event fires when first generation of `li` elements are clicked.

How can I solve this?.

Comment: There are many different ways of solving this. An inefficient one is by adding a condition inside your event that runs a check, perhaps looking to see if it's contained in another `<li>` element, before firing the alert. A more efficient one would be to make your event trigger more targeted. You could run a loop once on page load, that would add individual listeners to each of the `<li>` elements that you want to trigger the event. One solution requires giving the one level of elements its own class, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class

Comment: Well this "perhaps looking to see if it's contained in another <li> element, before firing the alert" was my first approach, but then I realized that the element clicked was the first Li itself, so I have nothing to check before the alert because this wasn't the nested element. Adding $('.menu > li li').click(function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); }); solve the problem because i am telling to the code to check this event first (bubbling effect) then stops propagation of any other event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **second LI** is inside the **first LI**.

Use:

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

OR

```
e.preventDefault();
```

[stopPropagation Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: I'm trying that, but this method stops the propagation of the event, what i understand is that if I click on second LI the first event to be fired will be the first Li not the second, stop propagation is only avoiding the method won't fire twice. What i want is that the event never happend if I click on the second Li.

Comment: @DiegoArturo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that the events happends up side down. I add : 
$('.menu > li li').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
To the code and worked.