# How do I make multiple buttons within the same class call to the same parameter function inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with 3 different buttons labeled 1 - 3. Currently, all 3 buttons use an inline event that passes its innerHTML as a parameter:

```
<div class="theClass">
    <button onclick="doThing(this.innerHTML)">1</button>
    <button onclick="doThing(this.innerHTML)">2</button>
    <button onclick="doThing(this.innerHTML)">3</button>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    function doThing(num){
        ...
    }
</script>
```

In an effort to both avoid redundancy and avoid inline scripting, I want to know how it would be possible to do this without an inline for each button. How would I make multiple buttons within the same class call the same external script? That is to say, how can I format a function to recognize that a button inside a designated class has been clicked, get the innerHTML of that button, and then pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript click event listener on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can select all buttons with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), loop through the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a `click` event listener that calls `doThing` and passes the element's `innerHTML` as a parameter to each button:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', function(){ doThing(this.innerHTML) }))


function doThing(html){
  console.log(html)
}
```

```html
<div class="theClass">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use event delegation by adding a `click` event listener to the document and checking whether the target is a button (with [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)), and if so, call `doThing`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.matches('button')){
    doThing(e.target.innerHTML)
  }
})
function doThing(html){
  console.log(html)
}
```

```html
<div class="theClass">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: They want to select all buttons inside a parent element with a specific class, so you probably want `document.querySelectorAll(".theClass button")`