# Toggle Rotate Arrows on Click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating multiple arrows that rotate when clicked. However, I'm getting an error "div.addEventListener is not a function" when using an addEventListener. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
(function (document) {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
  var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow");
  var open = false;

  div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (open) {
      icon.className = "fa fa-arrow-down";
    } else {
      icon.className = "fa fa-arrow-down rotate";
    }

    open = !open;
  });
})(document);
```

```css
.fa-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.fa-arrow-down.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down arrow"></i>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down arrow"></i>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down arrow"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method of **Document** interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name. It returns array like object, so way of accessing that `div` should be like accessing certain element of array.

You can use `for` loop

```
(function (document) {
  const div = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
  const divLen = div.length;
  let open = false;

  for(let i = 0; i < divLen; ++i) {
    div[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      const icon = this.getElementsByClassName("arrow");
      if (open) {
        icon.className = "fa fa-arrow-down";
      } else {
        icon.className = "fa fa-arrow-down rotate";
      }

      open = !open;
    }); 
  }
})(document);
```

Here's ES6 example of `forEach()` loop

```
(function(document) {
  const div = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
  let open = false;

  div.forEach(function(elem) { 
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const icon = elem.getElementsByClassName("arrow")[0];
      if (open) {
        icon.className = "fa fa-arrow-down";
      } else {
        icon.className = "fa fa-arrow-down rotate";
      }
     open = !open;
    });
  });
})(document);
```

Comment: This is just for the first container, why don't you use a loop to apply this for all the container elements?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was caused by you trying to **bind event to an array** instead of the element due to **getElementsByClassName** will return **[HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#return_value)** which is type of array.

You can refer this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)** which explained why bind event to array was not working.

I assuming you are using Vanilla JS only, first get all the elements which you want trigger the click event by class name, which is `container` class:

```
/* getElementsByClassName return array */
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
```

Then you have to loop though these divs:

```
/* loop through divs array */
Array.from(divs).forEach(function (div) {
    /* only you bind "click" event to "div" at here */
});
```

And here only you bind "click" event to your div, following code will find the `arrow` class elements in the `container` class and toggle the `open` class.

```
div.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    /* get the clicked element, which is the "container" */
    const clickedElement = event.currentTarget;

    /* find "arrow" class elements in "container" */
    const arrows = clickedElement.getElementsByClassName("arrow");

    /* loop through each "arrow" class element and toggle the "open" class name */
    Array.from(arrows).forEach(function (arrow) {
        arrow.classList.toggle("open");
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
(function(document) {
  /* getElementsByClassName return array */
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

  /* loop through divs array, bind the click event to each div */
  Array.from(divs).forEach(function(div) {
    div.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      /* get the clicked element, which is the "container" */
      const clickedElement = event.currentTarget;

      /* find "arrow" class elements in "container" */
      const arrows = clickedElement.getElementsByClassName("arrow");

      /* loop through each "arrow" class element and toggle the "open" class name */
      Array.from(arrows).forEach(function(arrow) {
        arrow.classList.toggle('open');
      });
    });
  });
})(document);
```

```css
.fa-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.fa-arrow-down.open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down arrow"></i>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down arrow"></i>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down arrow"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I was a bit confused there but now I understand. Thank you so much! Before I usually used getElementById and the addEventListener did work. But now that I need multiple containers/arrows and I got confused about why div.addEventListener didn't work.

Comment: **getElementById** did work was because ID is unique and it always return one element. But with class name is possible to have multiple elements. So the way you select multiple container by **getElementsByClassName** was correct, just you need to loop though each container and **addEventListener** to each of them, this is by using **Vanilla JS**. If you using **jQuery**, there will be more shorten code way: `$( ".container" ).click(function() { /* ... */ });` which allows you to bind click event to all elements with class name `container`.