# How can I find the Class Name of this button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set a click on this button with the code below using class name or id name but I am unable to find it.

```
<a href="mobile/register.php" class="primary-btn text-uppercase" style="margin-bottom:5px; color: #569EA4!important;"> <i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-2x" style="font-size: 15px;"></i> Register</a>
```

I tried it this way but is not working

```
document.getElementsByClassName(“primary-btn text-uppercase”).click();
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(“primary-btn text-uppercase”)[0]` maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript click event listener on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)

Comment: If you want to click on a single element it's better to select that element with id

Comment: @GrafiCode I gave it a try but it didn't work

Comment: @AsaduzzamanAtik me too I prefer using Id but it seems the button doesn't have an Id, if you can get the Id from the above code I will be very happy

Comment: You need an constant selector to get any information from an element, you are not providing the correct selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.querySelector(".primary-btn.text-uppercase").click();

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna reach both class at the same time:
`document.querySelector('text-uppercase.primary-btn')`

You can't put a space between classes when you use getElementsByClassName.

`document.getElementsByClassName(“text-uppercase”)`
or
`document.getElementsByClassName(“primary-btn”)`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your kindness, I really learnt a lot  from your answers

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a query selector like this,

```
document.querySelector(".primary-btn.text-uppercase").addEventListener('click' , function(){
    console.log("clicked") ; 
} )
```

but you should always do this with ids.

Answer (score 0):

You try to select 2 classes(`primary-btn` and `text-uppercase`) at the same time

```js
const myBtn = document.querySelector(".primary-btn");
myBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("some data");
});
```